# XMl layout file does not recognising string created in strings.xml

Tags: android

I have created new string in strings.xml and saved it.
When i am trying to use it in my layout.xml i get this error:

no resource found that matches the given name (at'text' with value '@string/breadth')

**the xml code where i am trying to use the strin is:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2F4F4F"
    android:text="@string/breadth"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

the string created is:

```
    <string name="breadth ">Breadth in cms</string>
```

please help

Comment: You have a _space_ after "breadth" in your `<string name="breadth ">Breadth in cms</string>`

Comment: such an easy mistake. thank You it works.

Comment: No problem. Happens to the best of us. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Instead of:

```
<string name="breadth ">Breadth in cms</string>
```

use:

```
<string name="breadth">Breadth in cms</string>
```

Note the removed space ().

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from your string `name="breadth "` in your string.xml file as below:

> ```
> <string name="breadth">Breadth in cms</string>
> ```